# Convert arrays stored in a pandas columns to a new dataframe columns , append and map the resulting array values to the original dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Python newbie here- I am comfortable with pandas (however, I know next to nothing when it comes to arrays).

I have a dataframe `df` with four columns namely:  `Name`, `colA`, `Income`, `colB`

- My primary goal is to carry out data analysis on this dataset, however the challenge I am having is the presence of arrays in two columns of my dataset (see below- `colA` and `colB`).
- The key thing to know- `colA` and `colB` are features extracted from image data.

I want to do the following :

1. convert the arrays in `colA` and `colB` to regular columns as seen in `Name` and `Income`
2. Map the converted arrays(the new columns) back to the corresponding row/index number  in the original dataframe
3. Assign column names to the new columns of the mapped arrays such as `colA1`, `colA2`, `colA3`,`colB1`,`colB2`,`colB3`,`colB4`...... (so that one will be able to know where the new columns were derived from)

```
df

index, Name,  colA                           ,Income,     colB 
1. Peter,  [[[3,4],[3,9],[3,0],[2,1]]]      , 32100,   [[3,4,1,3,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[6,5,0,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1]]
2. John ,  [[[1,2],[3,5],[1,0],[0,1]]]      , 43256,   [[5,4,2,3,4],[5,1,2,2,5],[7,5,0,1,2],[4,2,1,1,3]]
3. Mark ,  [[[5,8],[5,9],[1,0],[1,4]]]      , 29811,   [[4,4,1,3,2],[6,2,2,2,8],[6,1,0,1,3],[9,2,1,9,9]]
4. Jane ,  [[[8,4],[1,2],[5,3],[1,8]]]      ,134500,   [[3,4,7,3,7],[1,2,5,6,2],[6,5,1,3,2],[9,2,3,2,5]]
5. Jill ,  [[[6,6],[2,1],[1,1],[5,6]]]      ,233120,   [[5,4,5,3,9],[1,2,5,2,0],[0,5,0,4,2],[1,5,1,6,1]]
```

Desired output :

```
# the new df  should look something like the example below or  something more appropriate for data analysis in a pandas dataframe 

index Name, Income  colA1, colA2, colA3,colA4,colA5,ColB1,colB2,colB3,colB4                              
1. Peter, 32100,  3,4,3,9,3,0,2,1 3,4,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,1,6,5,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1
2. John , 43256,  1,2,3,5,1,0,0,1,5,4,2,3,4,5,1,2,2,5,7,5,0,1,2,4,2,1,1,3
3. Mark , 29811   5,8,5,9,1,0,1,4 4,4,1,3,2,6,2,2,2,8,6,1,0,1,3,9,2,1,9,9
4. Jane , 134500,  8,4,1,2,5,3,1,8,3,4,7,3,7,1,2,5,6,2,6,5,1,3,2,9,2,3,2,5
5. Jill , 233120, 6,6,2,1,1,1,5,6,5,4,5,3,9,1,2,5,2,0,0,5,0,4,2,1,5,1,6,1
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a trial code because I don't know my way with arrays. Thanks for your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Flatten the lists inside the columns

```
df['colA']=df['colA'].apply(lambda x: [item for sublist in x[0] for item in sublist])

0    [3, 4, 3, 9, 3, 0, 2, 1]
1    [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1]

df['colB']=df['colB'].apply(lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist])

0    [3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 6, 5, 0, 1, 1, ...
1    [5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 5, 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Step 2: Create Columns from lists with a prefix, concat them into our dataframe and drop the original cols:

```
 df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.colA.tolist(), index= df.index).add_prefix('colA'),df,],axis=1).drop('colA',axis=1)

 df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.colB.tolist(), index= df.index).add_prefix('colB'),df,],axis=1).drop('colB',axis=1)



   colB0  colB1  colB2  colB3  colB4  colB5  colB6  colB7  colB8  colB9  ...  \
0      3      4      1      3      1      1      2      2      2      1  ...   
1      5      4      2      3      4      5      1      2      2      5  ...   

   colA0  colA1  colA2  colA3  colA4  colA5  colA6  colA7   Name  Income  
0      3      4      3      9      3      0      2      1  Peter   32100  
1      1      2      3      5      1      0      0      1   John   43256
```